# What to do next for preventing the overfitting?

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network, overfitting, tensorflow

I'm doing a two-class image segmentation problem using fully convolutional networks, and got the following `loss` curves and `learning_rate` change curves. From the `loss` curves, it seems the network is overfitting from the training set. I have used the weight decay and changing learning rate policy. Are there any other methods to preventing the overfitting problem?

The `loss` curves for training data and validation data are (blue line is loss curve on validation data):

[image: loss curves]

The `learning_rate` policy is piece-wise changing. It seems lowering the learning rate cannot change the loss values a lot.

[image: learning_rate curves]

Answer (score 1):

Here are two ideas:

- Add random noise to the training set images. This should make the training set harder and improve the generalization error.
- Early stopping. I suggest this because your error on the validation set has a "U" shape. For this you would need to store a copy of the parameters every time the error on validation data improves. The training could stop when the error does not decrease for a given number of epochs, and at the end of the training you keep only the set of parameters that achieved the best error on the validation set.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your kind answer! Yeah, I have tried this.